# A question on normal subgroup concerning equality among complex

Tags: abstract-algebra

If A,B,C are normal subgroups of a group G where B is a subset of A. Then show that A intersection BC equals B(A intersection C).
I m a newbie in abstract algebra n i m new to rigourous mathematical proof. I know that to show two sets are equal i must show that each one is a subset of the other. Plz solve this question

Comment: You can also upvote any answers you found helpful (either mine or others that come in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x\in A\cap BC$, then $x\in A$ and $x=bc$ for some $b\in B$ and $c\in C$. By assumption $b\in A$ because $B$ is contained in $A$. Subgroups are closed under the operation, so $b^{-1}(bc)=c\in A$. Thus $x\in B(A\cap C)$ because $c\in A\cap C$.

Conversely, if $x\in B(A\cap C)$, then $x=bd$ for some $b\in B$ and $d\in A\cap C$. Since $b,d\in A$, $bd\in A$, so $x\in A$. Since $d\in A\cap C$ it follows that $d\in C$, hence $x\in BC$. Thus $x\in A\cap BC$ and we are done.